# Ember transitions in realtime

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We use ember 1.8 along with https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet to make the transitions on the application look more like other mobile apps ,

However now we need this to work more like the "Tumblr" app where when an item on list is swiped the next view with details will slide over in realtime based on the swiping pattern ,etc that is more you swipe the more of the next view will appear and if you slide on opposite direction you stay on the same page.

Is it possible to do this in Ember or this kind of transition is not possible with our current app?

Please let me know if the question is not worded correctly.

We wanted to be sure this is achieveable in the ember before we try that route.

Comment: are you asking specifically about the animation (as you transition to a new route) or something else?

Comment: Yeah specifically about the animation as we transition.. we would like the new view to be displayed partially as we swipe and fully when the swipe is complete. 

we already do have the animated transitions but they dont react to the user touch, instead happen automatically